# SVG Спрайт, кроссбраузерность

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, кроссбраузерность, svg-спрайт

Есть проблема с одинаковым отображением SVG спрайта между Safari, Google Chrome и Firefox последних версий.
**Safari:**
[image: Safari] 


**Chrome:**
[image: Chrome]

```
.features__image {
  width: 165px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("img/_sprite/sprite.svg");
  background-position: 52px -178px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 75px;
}
```

*Отмечу, что если для еще большей наглядности указать: `background-positon: 0 0;`, то совсем непонятно, почему в Safari границы спрайта не прижимаются к границам контейнера.

***Для наглядности, часть спрайта, где видно, что доступная рабочая область отсутствует за пределами объектов.
[image: Спрайта]

Comment: а вы сборщиком спрайт собираете?